Ctrl-C is propagated from gdb client to server when invoked from same command line
When I start gdb-server and gdb-client with one command like gdb-server 1>/dev/null & arm-none-eabi-gdb the server is killed when I hit ctrl-c in gdb-client to stop the current process. It looks like the sigint is propagated from gdb-client to the shell.
This command line is passed to a docker container (docker run -it --rm my_image gdb_server...) so starting both processing individually is not possible.
Any way to stop gdb-client propagating the signal?
This is the complete command line that causes the issue:
bash -l -c "/opt/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer -if swd -device Cortex-M33 -speed auto -port 2326 -vd -halt -reportuseraction -nogui -endian little -singlerun & arm-none-eabi-gdb -ex \"target extended-remote :2326\" -ex \"c\""
After hitting ctrl-c you get:
^CDebugger requested to halt target...
...Target halted (PC = 0x00000754)
Restoring target state and closing J-Link connection...
Shutting down...
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Connection reset by peer.

The remote communication error is caused by the server being stopped simultaneously.
if the command is not encapsulated in bash -l -c, ctrl-c is not stopping the server side and it works as expected

Background processes do not receive keyboard-generated signals.  That's part of what it means to be in the background.  Possibly the gdb client is forwarding the signal, but it seems more likely that you left out some relevant piece of information that explains what's really going on.  This sort of thing is why we generally want to see a [mre].  Please edit the question to include one.

@JohnBollinger, I included a concrete example. But you're right, some essential info was missing. By trying this I figured out that the root cause seems to be the encapsulation of the command in bash -l -c which is the common way to execute commands in Docker.

It seems that adding -i to make the shell interactive, solves the issue.
